# JAX-RS - CORS only works for application/xml, not for application/json

Tags: json, ajax, cors, jax-rs

I have a strange problem involving: CORS, XMLHttpRequest and JAX-RS.
We want to make an ajax-call to our REST-API (Java, JAX-RS) at **service.myapi.com** from **mysite.com**

This request fails when we use the header `Accept: 'application/json'`

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: 'https://service.myapi.com/rest/machine/metadata',
    headers: {
      'Accept': 'application/json',
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      'Session-Token': myToken
    },
    data: JSON.stringify({
       'machine-number': 1
    })
 });
```

**Gets the following message from the browser:**

*Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at https://service.myapi.com/rest/machine/metadata. (Reason: CORS header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' missing).*

However if I change to `Accept: 'application/xml'` **it works as expected (!)**.

**This is how i looks on the server**

*Filter that adds CORS headers*

```
  private static final String ALLOW_HEADERS = createAllowHeaders();

  @Override
  public void doFilter(ServletRequest req, ServletResponse res, FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {

    HttpServletRequest request = (HttpServletRequest) req;
    HttpServletResponse response = (HttpServletResponse) res;

    try {
        chain.doFilter(request, response);
    } catch(Exception e) {
        response.setStatus(500);
    } finally  {
        response.addHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
        response.addHeader("Access-Control-Expose-Headers","Session-Token");
        response.addHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", ALLOW_HEADERS);
        response.addHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials", "true");
        response.addHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS, HEAD");
    }
  }

  private static String createAllowHeaders() {
    return new StringJoiner(", ")
            .add("Access-Control-Allow-Headers")
            .add("X-Requested-With")
            .add("Access-Control-Request-Method")
            .add("Access-Control-Request-Headers")
            .add("origin")
            .add("content-type") 
            .add("accept")
            .add("authorization")
            .add("Session-Token")
            .toString(); 
  }
```

*The method with JAX-RS annotations that handles the request*

```
@Path("/metadata")
@POST
@Consumes({ APPLICATION_XML, APPLICATION_JSON })
@Produces({ APPLICATION_XML, APPLICATION_JSON })
public Response getMetadata(@Context HttpServletRequest req, MetadataRequest m) {
  //...
}
```

I don't know why it won't work when using `Accept: 'application/json'`. Tested in Chrome and Firefox. Get the same result in both browsers.

Comment: This is the expected behavior per-spec. If the value of `Content-type` is `application/json`, it’s not what CORS defines as a **simple header** and so that triggers a CORS preflight request.

See the ***request's unsafe-request flag is set and… a header in request's header list is not a simple header*** case in step 8 of [the ***Main fetch*** algorithm in the spec https://fetch.spec.whatwg.org/#main-fetch

The only `Content-type` values that won’t trigger a CORS preflight request are `text/plain`, `multipart/form-data`, `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`.